# Parent annotation in Angular2 alpha.31

Tags: annotations, typescript, angular

I am trying to add Parent annotation in Angular2 alpha31.

I use this import statement:

```
import {Parent} from 'angular2/annotations';
```

I have also added the following to angular2.d.ts:

```
declare module "angular2/annotations" {
    function Parent(): (target: any) => any;
    function Ancestor(): (target: any) => any;
}
```

My .ts file looks like this:

```
/// <reference path='../../../../../typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts' />

import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Parent} from 'angular2/annotations';
import {Messenger} from 'components/messenger/messenger';

@Component({
    selector : 'compose',
    hostInjector : [Messenger]
})

@View({
    templateUrl: 'components/compose/compose.html'
})

export class Compose {

    title : string;
    message : string;
    messenger : Messenger;

    constructor(@Parent messenger:Messenger){
        this.messenger = messenger;
    }
}
```

But I keep getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: decorator is not a function

What am I missing? :)

Thanks!

Comment: meanwhile in alpha-32 `@Parent` got deleted, try `@Ancestor` instead. also do a `npm ls` to confirm if you really have alpha 31, you might accidentally have alpha 32

Comment: As mentioned [@Parent has been removed](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/3159). It shouldn't affect alpha 31 though. I would check your typescript compile options, especially `target` and whether `emitDecoratorMetadata` is set.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem:

```
constructor(@Ancestor @Inject(forwardRef(() => Messenger)) messenger : Messenger) {
    this.title = "I am the composer! I am child element of Messenger"
}
```

Using this and removing "hostInjector : [ Messenger ]" fixed my problem. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way to do this in alpha-37 is @Host.

```
constructor(@Host() tabs:Tabs)
```

Instead of `@Parent`, this has at least proved successful to me.

Comment: I get following error using (@Host() foo:Foo): EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for Bar(undefined @Host(), BazService). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations.